# activemq failover using multiple instances in master slave mode on same linux machine

Tags: activemq-classic, multiple-instances, failover

I have setup ActiveMQ mulitple instances to achieve failover in master slave mode in windows.
While setting up the same i just created 3 instances under bin folder without changing any port and started all 3 instances one by one. First instance became master and remaining were in slave mode until I stopped master instance.

Now I am trying to achieve the same in Linux environment. First instance starts successfully but when I start second instance in a different window it throws below error:

**ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([instance2, ID:132vm6-57227-1478597606120-0:1], java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use)**
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 (instance2, ID:132vm6-57227-1478597606120-0:1) is shutting down
 INFO | Connector openwire stopped
 INFO | Connector amqp stopped
 INFO | Connector stomp stopped
 INFO | Connector mqtt stopped
 INFO | Connector ws stopped
 INFO | PListStore:[/opt/apache-activemq-5.14.0/bin/instance2/data/instance2/tmp_storage] stopped
 INFO | Stopping async queue tasks
 INFO | Stopping async topic tasks
 INFO | Stopped KahaDB
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 (instance2, ID:132vm6-57227-1478597606120-0:1) uptime 0.585 seconds
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 (instance2, ID:132vm6-57227-1478597606120-0:1) is shutdown
 INFO | Closing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@4233871a: startup date [Tue Nov 08 15:03:24 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
 WARN | Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@4233871a: startup date [Tue Nov 08 15:03:24 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:884)[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:843)[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook.run(SpringContextHook.java:30)[activemq-spring-5.14.0.jar:5.14.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:875)[activemq-broker-5.14.0.jar:5.14.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.stop(XBeanBrokerService.java:122)[activemq-spring-5.14.0.jar:5.14.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:629)[activemq-broker-5.14.0.jar:5.14.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:73)[activemq-spring-5.14.0.jar:5.14.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_65]

I am using ActiveMQ 5.14 version.
If anybody has encountered a similar issue, kindly provide your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

To get multiple instances of ActiveMQ running on the same machine, you need to change the ports that they try to open. There are (at least) 3 ports that need to be changed:

- The `transportConnector` ports that accept messaging traffic. These are defined in the`activemq.xml` file. Typically you only need the `openwire` one - this is 61616 by default; I usually change this in the other ActiveMQ instances to 61626, 61636 etc. You can usually comment out the others if you don't intend to use them.
- The Jetty HTTP port. This is defined in the `jetty.xml` file. The default is 8161, set the next ones to 8162, 8163 etc.
- The JMX port. This one's a bit tricky, as you need to stick a piece of config into the `activemq.xml` to explicitly define it as follows:

  ```
  <managementContext>
      <managementContext createConnector="true" connectorPort="1099"/>
  </managementContext>
  ```

You can then change this to 1199, 1299 on the other instances. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Jakub .. thanks for your inputs, I have already tested the setup mentioned by you and its working for me as well. But when I try running multiple instances without changing ports it throws error in Linux but works fine in Windows through command line. Wondering if this can work in windows then why not in Linux?

Comment: Chances are that your data directory is pointing to different locations in each of the Linux broker installations. As such, all of them try to come up at the same time (i.e. there is no master-slave). On Windows, it sounds as though you set it up correctly. A broker will it open up its ports only if it considers itself in "master" mode.

Comment: @Jakub, Can you please post the sample activemq. xml for failover?

Comment: Just set the ACTIVEMQ_DATA environment variable to some full directory, it will get picked up by the startup script. e.g. `c:\activemq\shared-data`.